# To fetch latest folder in Ubuntu server

Tags: mongodb, shell, ubuntu

My folder has following directories

```
mongo_2018_06_21
mongodump-2018-05-09
mongodump-2018-06-19
mongodump-2018-06-25
UQDBclone_201805070235
UQDBclone_201806280424
```

The mongodump folders with date get created when given a release. What should I do to select only the latest mongodump folder?

Comment: Please elaborate a bit

Answer (score 1):

try this it will work in ubuntu and mac

```
ls -art | grep mongodump | tail -n 1
```